# How to get response body to retrofit exception?

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit, okhttp

I am trying to connect to rest service via retrofit in android application. I am getting responses. But when there is some error response from the service, conversion exception occurs and now I want to do some actions based on the response body. But I am getting response body as NULL. But retrofit log has a error message. Why is this happening.

```
D/Reftofit log(24856): OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1397527055676
D/Reftofit log(24856): OkHttp-Response-Source: NETWORK 200
D/Reftofit log(24856): OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1397527055492
D/Reftofit log(24856): Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
D/Reftofit log(24856): X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10
D/Reftofit log(24856): {"result":"Invalid Token ID"}
```

Code:

```
public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
    String response = null;
    TokenError tokenError = (TokenError) retrofitError.getBodyAs(TokenError.class);
    response = tokenError.getErrorDetails();
    Log.e(TAG, response);
    if (response != null && response.contains("Invalid Token ID")) {
        GroupDataProvider.getInstance().onFailure();
    }

}
```

Here I am getting `tokenError` as `null`. I don't know why? Do I need to set something with rest adapter so that the response will be passed to retrofit error object.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try this code:

```
@Override
public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
    String json =  new String(((TypedByteArray)error.getResponse().getBody()).getBytes());
    Log.v("failure", json.toString());
}
```

with **Retrofit 2.0**

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
    String message = t.getMessage();
    Log.d("failure", message);
}
```

Comment: Simple and amazing. This line saved a complete class.

Comment: what is RestError class ?. i cannot import it

Comment: @Cabezas Be careful with the first example approach (Retrofit 1.9), as there is a bug when casting to a TypedByteArray if you are using LogLevel.NONE. See https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/953

Answer (score 5):

if error in String format:

```
public Sring getErrorBodyAsString(RetrofitError error) {    
      return (String) error.getBodyAs(String.class)
}
```

if you need custom object:

```
class ErrorResponse {
   @SerializedName("error")
   int errorCode;

   @SerializedName("msg")
   String msg;
}

public T getErrorBody(RetrofitError error, Class<T> clazz) {    
      return (T) error.getBodyAs(clazz);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your server should return 4xx HTTP error code to get this working.

When your server returns HTTP 200 this mean successful response and it will be processed with `onSuccess` branch. Likely your object which you pass to `Callback<Object>` should be ready to handle both success and error result.

To make sure this is the case you can check if `RetrofitError` is actually a `JsonParseException` by adding next snippet:

```
public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
    Log.v(TAG, error.getMessage());
};
```

Comment: `error.getMessage()` doesn't return the body sent from REST service but something like "406 Not Acceptable" (in case you receive a 406). See answer by Cabezas to actually get the body.

Answer (score 1):

you need use getErrorStream() for this.

> If the HTTP response indicates that an error occurred,
>   getInputStream() will throw an IOException. Use getErrorStream() to
>   read the error response. The headers can be read in the normal way
>   using getHeaderFields().

Ref: [github issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/676)