# Retrofit 2 can't upload a file with two additional separate string parameters

Tags: android, file-upload, retrofit, android-networking, retrofit2

***Read edit at bottom of the question for possible alternative solution until the solution is found***.

This is a successful post file with two parameters using POSTMan. I am trying to do the same with retrofit but receive BadRequest.

**PostMan Settings:**

[image]

**Chrome Network Post Details:**
[image]

Now here is how I am doing this in Android but failing:

**Retrofit Service Interface:**

```
@Multipart
@POST("jobDocuments/upload")
Call<ResponseBody> upload(@Part("file") MultipartBody.Part file,@Part("folder") MultipartBody.Part folder,@Part("name") MultipartBody.Part name);
```

This is my @Background method to run the network request with above service generated

```
CustDataClient service =
            ServiceGenerator.createService(CustDataClient.class);
    File file = new File(fileUri.getPath());
    // create RequestBody instance from file
    RequestBody requestFile =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

    MultipartBody.Part fileData =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", fileName, requestFile);
    MultipartBody.Part folder =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("folder", "LeadDocuments");
    MultipartBody.Part name =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("name", fileName);
    // finally, execute the request
    Call<ResponseBody> call = service.upload(fileData,folder,name);
    try {
        Response<ResponseBody> rr = call.execute();
        ResponseBody empJobDocsResult = rr.body();//Bad Request here :(
        Log.v("Upload", "success");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Upload error:", ex.getMessage());
    }
```

**Here is my Web Api Method:**

```
 [Route("upload")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Upload()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
        {
            // Get the uploaded image from the Files collection
            var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];

            if (httpPostedFile != null)
            {
                // Validate the uploaded image(optional)
                var folder = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["folder"];
                var fileName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["name"];
                fileName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) ? httpPostedFile.FileName : fileName;
                // Get the complete file path
                var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + folder), fileName);

                // Save the uploaded file to "UploadedFiles" folder
                httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);

                return Ok(new OkMessage { Message = "File uploaded successfully", Path = "/Files/" + folder + "/" + fileName });
            }
        }

        return BadRequest("File not uploaded");
    }
```

Please help where I am wrong and how to achieve this, is there any easy alternative to retrofit?

**[Edit]**
This code is working successfully, Thanks to [koush/ion](https://github.com/koush/ion):

```
Ion.with(getContext())
                            .load("POST", "http://www.dgheating.com/api/jobDocuments/upload")
                            .setMultipartParameter("folder", "LeadDocuments")
                            .setMultipartParameter("name", fileName)
                            .setMultipartFile("file", new File(imagePath))
                            .asJsonObject()
                            .setCallback(...);
```

Comment: I had the same issue with Android, in to be precise, with 4.1.1; Now using the example with Ion the problem is solved and now I can easily upload files (images in my case) without problems. You should post the Ion edit as a response (I guess).

Comment: No that's not the solution of a problem but an alternative (avoiding problem).

Comment: this sucks. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: nvm, I just saw your edit and Ion will be.

Answer (score 21):

I faced similar issue here: [Android with Retrofit2 OkHttp3 - Multipart POST Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320205/android-with-retrofit2-okhttp3-multipart-post-error)

I got my problem solved after taking @TommySM suggestion. If is still unclear to you, I think this is the solution:

```
@Multipart
@POST("jobDocuments/upload")
Call<ResponseBody> upload(
    @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
    @Part("folder") RequestBody folder,
    @Part("name")   RequestBody name);

File file = new File(fileUri.getPath());

// Assume your file is PNG
RequestBody requestFile =
        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), file);

MultipartBody.Part fileData =
        MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", fileName, requestFile);

RequestBody folder = RequestBody.create(
        MediaType.parse("text/plain"),
        "LeadDocuments");

RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(
        MediaType.parse("text/plain"),
        fileName);

// finally, execute the request
Call<ResponseBody> call = service.upload(fileData, folder, name);
```

The important part is to use `MediaType.parse("text/plain")` for `MediaType` of String parameter (I believe your case is: folder & name parameter), using `okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM` is a mistake.

See these screenshots for the comparison:

1) Problematic POST

[image]

2) Correct POST

[image]

Comment: best solution. saved my life

Comment: Is it possible for you to answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60428238/upload-file-using-both-multipart-and-json-key-value-pairs-with-retrofit2/60428382#60428382

Answer (score 9):

So, hope it's no too late, and if so - it might help somebody else :) my 2 cents about this is after having the same problem a while back:

The service definition, using `@Part` only (modify field names according to what your server expects)

```
//Single image MultiPart
@Multipart
@POST("user/imageupload")
Call<ResponseBody> upload(@Part("userfile") RequestBody file, @Part("userid") RequestBody description);
```

And for the magic trick, I refer to both parts just as `RequestBody`, using the `MediaType.parse()` to each one with it's own type, relying on the `@Multipart` definition for the request itself, no need for `form-data` stuff, the same works for multiple files, and multiple fields:

```
private static final String IMG_JPEG = "image/jpeg";
private static final String TXT_PLAIN = "text/plain";

public void uploadImageMultipart(Uri uri, final CustomEventListener<String> listener)
{
    RequestBody fileBody;
    RequestBody textBody;
    File file = new File(uri.getPath());
    Call<ResponseBody> requestCall;

    fileBody = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse(IMG_JPEG), file);
    textBody = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse(TXT_PLAIN), String.valueOf(SettingsManager.getUserID()));

      requestCall = serviceCaller.upload(fileBody, textBody);
      requestCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>()
      {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> rawResponse)
        {
            try
            {
                String response = rawResponse.body().string();
                //from here it's your show....
                listener.getResult("Got it");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                        e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable throwable)
        {

        }
    });
}
```

(I use a listener to return the callback response to a different part of the app (e.g. a calling activity)).

This definitely sends the file/s and the text field, other problems would probably stem from the server side.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: your solution works best for me. I faced similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320205/android-with-retrofit2-okhttp3-multipart-post-error. The issue was with the body part which is String, got it fixed with MediaType of `text/plain` like suggested:  `textBody = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse(TXT_PLAIN), String.valueOf(SettingsManager.getUserID()));
`

Comment: @shuwnyuantee Glad I could help, you can also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172496/android-volley-how-to-isolate-requests-in-another-class/30604191#30604191 for a clean way to use the CustomEventListener interface (the general idea is similar between Volley and Retrofit)

Answer (score 4):

Using Retrofit 2, you need to use either OkHttp’s RequestBody or MultipartBody.Part classes and encapsulate your file into a request body. Let’s have a look at the interface definition for file uploads.
Have you seen https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server

Comment: Yes all above code in the question was actually started from this tutorial. And its almost identical except the additional two string parameters. Plus Ion library is working great with same data and settings.

Answer (score 1):

**Interface for Retrofit (API)**

```
public interface API {

    String NAME = "name";
    String FOLDER = "folder";
    @Multipart
    @POST("/api/jobDocuments/upload")
    Call<JsonResponse> uploadFile(
        @Part(NAME) String name,
        @Part(FOLDER) String folder,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
}
```

**Response Class (JsonResponse)**

```
public class JsonResponse {

    @SerializedName("$id")
    public String id;
    @SerializedName("Message")
    public String message;
    @SerializedName("Path")
    public String path;

    public JsonResponse(String id, String message, String path) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
        this.path = path;
    }
}
```

**API call from application**

```
Retrofit retrofit;

private void postImage() {
    String URL = "http://www.dgheating.com/";

    //your file location
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Image.png");

    //parameters
    String NAME = file.getName();
    String FOLDER = "LeadDocuments";
    String FILE = "file";

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()))
            .build();
    API api = retrofit.create(API.class);
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(FILE, NAME, requestBody);
    Call<JsonResponse> call = api.uploadFile(NAME, FOLDER, part);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonResponse> call, Response<JsonResponse> response) {
            //response.body()           null
            //response.code()           500

            //https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1321
            Converter<ResponseBody, JsonResponse> errorConverter
                    = retrofit.responseBodyConverter(JsonResponse.class, new Annotation[0]);
            try {
                JsonResponse jsonResponse = errorConverter.convert(response.errorBody());
                Log.e("error", "id:" + jsonResponse.id);                //1
                Log.e("error", "message:" + jsonResponse.message);      //An error has occurred
                Log.e("error", "path:" + jsonResponse.path);             //null
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

**Error in fields, because of any of these server issue**

1. [Google](https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=retrofit%20error%20has%20occurred&oq=retrofit%20error%20has%20occurred)
2. [HTTP 500 response using retrofit, but Post request through Postman gives desired response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34187132/http-500-response-using-retrofit-but-post-request-through-postman-gives-desired)
3. [How to get response body to retrofit exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073439/how-to-get-response-body-to-retrofit-exception)
4. [Retrofit SocketTimeoutException (and/or http 500 error) on http-POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297996/retrofit-sockettimeoutexception-and-or-http-500-error-on-http-post)

Comment: I will check it soon and give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your service definition is wrong. Try

```
@Multipart
@POST("jobDocuments/upload")
Call<ResponseBody> upload(@Part("file") MultipartBody.Part file,@Part("folder") RequestBody folder,@Part("name") RequestBody name);
```

and

```
RequestBody folder =
        RequestBody.create(
                MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "LeadDocuments");
RequestBody name =
        RequestBody.create(
                MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), filename);
```

in your @Background method. This all assumes you are using Retrofit2.

Comment: No success with above correction too. Yes its retrofit2. :(

Comment: doesn't work, this exception throws: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Part parameters using the MultipartBody.Part must not include a part name in the annotation.`

Comment: Hesam, you shuld use @Part instead @Part("file").