# Retrofit Status code 500 in API as success

Tags: retrofit2

MY API returning  500 on the case of success instead of default 200, how can i handle it as success in retrofit 2.0.
Please help me .

Answer (score 1):

Check your

```
response.errorBody()
```

if it contains the valid response you can convert it to JSON by using [retrofit.responseBodyConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40863880/4754141)